# Exoplayer next and prev buttons doesn't work. The next button remains inactive/invisible

Tags: android, exoplayer

Below is the Code for next and previous buttons and its onclick method codes. Exoplayer doesn't fire the onclick methods. Please check, and suggest the required changes

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        exonext = findViewById(R.id.exo_next);
        exonext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        exoprev = findViewById(R.id.exo_prev);

exonext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (positionx<friends.size()) {

                    if (positionx == firstposition) {
                        positionx = positionx + 1;
                        String nextsong = friends.get(positionx);
                        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(nextsong), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                        player.prepare(mediaSource);
                        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);



                    } 
                     else {
                        positionx = positionx + 1;
                        String nextsong = friends.get(positionx);

                        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(nextsong), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                        player.prepare(mediaSource);
                        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);


                    }
                }
            }
        });

        exoprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (positionx<=0) {

                    if (positionx == firstposition) {
                        positionx = positionx - 1;
                        String nextsong = friends.get(positionx);

                        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(nextsong), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                        player.prepare(mediaSource);
                        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

                    } 

                   else {
                        positionx = positionx - 1;
                        String nextsong = friends.get(positionx);

                        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(nextsong), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                        player.prepare(mediaSource);
                        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);


                    }
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Also, how can i show next button always active/visible or there is any way to change exoplayer next and previous button ids in exo_player_control_view.xml file?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom controls for previous and next song to play use your custom icon/button and give the style of default like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/exo_prev"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/exo_center_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exo_screenlock"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exo_progress"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
```

and same for next button it will automatically work for you.You cannot change the id of previous butto. Why do you want to buid the thing that already you have in exoplayer. Just go for customization .